# Do not exist IID random variables $X, Y$ such that $X-Y \sim U[-1,1]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

This is an exercise from Williams, Proability with martingales.

> Prove that if $Z$ has the $U[-1,1]$ distribution, then $$\phi_Z(t) = \frac{\sin t}{t}$$ Then prove that do not exist IID random variables such that $X-Y \sim U[-1,1]$.

I calculated $\phi_Z(t)$, and for the second point I obtain that $$\phi_{X-Y}(t) = \phi_X(t) \phi_X(-t)$$ How to continue ?

Comment: What is $\phi_Z(t)$ here? (doesn't seem a likely density function for a uniform distribution, which is what the notation $U[-1,1]$ usually means.)

Comment: @coffeemath Characteristic function: $\phi_X:t\mapsto\phi_X(t)=E(e^{itX})$.

Comment: Hint: $$\phi_Z(3\pi/2)\lt0$$

Comment: @Did: so we have $$\phi_{X-Y}(3\pi /2) = \phi_X(3\pi /2) \phi_X(-3\pi /2)$$

Comment: @Did: do you mean that $\phi_X(3\pi /2) \phi_X(-3\pi /2) > 0$ ? I don't see why

Comment: You might "not see why" because you did not bother to read section 16.2 **Elementary** properties of CF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because a characteristic function (Fourier transform of a real function) is [hermitian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Properties_of_the_Fourier_transform) $\phi_X(-t)=\phi_X(t)^*$ (complex conjugate). Hence  $\phi_X(t)\phi_X(-t) = |\phi_X(t)|^2 \ge 0$. But $\sin(t)/t$ is negative for some values of $t$. Hence...

Comment: Nice! I did not know this little fact.