# Solving $X+Y\stackrel{d}{=}2Y$ with $X$ uniform on $[-1,1]$

Tags: probability, random-variables, characteristic-functions, independence

I have problems with the following question:
Let $X$ be the random variable such that $X\sim U[-1,1]$. Does there exist a random variable $Y$, independent to $X$, such that $X+Y\sim 2Y$?

I thought that uniqueness of characteristic function would help. So, we ask if there exists a variable Y with characteristic function $\phi(t)$, such that $\frac{\sin(t)}{t}\phi(t)=\phi(2t)$.  (And, of course $\phi(0)=1)$
I would be thankful for help.
**Edit**:
Proof by contradiction.
I will show that zeros of $\phi$ have $0$ as their accumulation point:
Notice that if $t\in(-\pi,\pi)$ we have: if $\phi(2t)=0$ then $\phi(t)=0 (*) $.

We just have to know if there exists any zero of $\phi$ in $(-\pi,\pi)$. $\phi(\pi)=\frac{2}{\pi}\phi(\frac{\pi}{2})$ and $\phi(-\pi)=\frac{-2}{\pi}\phi(\frac{-\pi}{2})$. So if $\phi(\frac{\pi}{2})\neq0$ and $\phi(-\frac{\pi}{2})\neq0$, then either $\phi(\pi)$ and $\phi(-\pi)$ or $\phi(\frac{\pi}{2})$ and $\phi(-\frac{\pi}{2})$ have opposite signs, so there exists zero of $\phi$ in $(-\pi,\pi)$. We know that $\phi(0)=1$, hence from $(*)$ there is a sequence of zeros of $\phi$ which converges to 0. Then, because $\phi$ is continuous $\phi(0)=0$.
Is it correct?

Comment: Check: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1122239/do-not-exist-iid-random-variables-x-y-such-that-x-y-sim-u-1-1?rq=1

Comment: Thank you. I've noticed that my question seems to be very similar, but I don't know how to use that task. Have you got any idea?

Comment: Hint: show that zeros of $\phi$ have $0$ as their accumulation point.

Comment: Thank you. It would be contradiction to $\phi(0)=1$ and the fact that characteristic function is continuous. Unfortunately, I can't see why it is true. When it comes to zeros of $\phi$ I see only that $\phi(2k\pi)=0$ and for $0<t<\pi$ if $\phi(2t)=0$ then $\phi(t)=0$.

Comment: Scratch that. Your approach is needed.

Comment: Re the approach in the post, note that any solution $\phi$ solves $\phi(\pi)=\frac{2}{\pi}\phi(\frac{\pi}{2})$ and $\phi(-\pi)=\frac{2}{\pi}\phi(\frac{-\pi}{2})$, not $\phi(-\pi)=\frac{-2}{\pi}\phi(\frac{-\pi}{2})$, hence the rest of the proof falls. (And actually, the identity in distribution **does have a (unique) solution**...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the distributional equation $$X+Y\stackrel{d}{=}2Y$$ for some fixed $X$, assuming, say, that $X$ is bounded, simply consider $$Y=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{X_k}{2^k}$$ with $(X_k)$ i.i.d. and distributed like $X$. Then the series on the RHS converges almost surely and its sum solves the desired distributional identity.

In terms of characteristic functions, this translates as $$\varphi_Y(t)=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\varphi_X\left(\frac{t}{2^k}\right)$$ In the particular case when $X$ is uniform on $(-1,1)$, the distribution of $Y$ has support $(-2,2)$, and it is characterized by its characteristic function $$\varphi_Y(t)=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(t/2^k)}{t/2^k}$$